# Compiler throws "ambiguous overload for operator"

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ambiguous, template-argument-deduction

I'm learning how to use std::chrono and I want to make a template class Timer easy to use (defined in `timer.h`). The testing program was successful and everything worked fine, until I tried to use my new Timer in a program with the definition of some template operators, which conflit with the operators used inside Timer.

Inside Timer I have to use `operator-` between two variables (`start_time` and `end_time`) of type `std::chrono::time_point`, in order to obtain the `duration` variable containing the elapsed time.

In another header (`algebra.h`) I implemented the overloading of the binary `operator-` to make the difference between two `std::vector` or two `std::array`, or also a user-defined container provided with `operator[]` and `size()` member function.

```
template<typename pointType>
pointType operator-(pointType a, const pointType & b){
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i){
        a[i] = a[i] - b[i];
    }
    return a;
}
```

When I try to include both `timer.h` and `algebra.h`, the compiler throws an error saying "ambiguous overload for operator-" suggesting, as possible candidates, both the operator in `algebra.h` and the one implemented in `<chrono>`.

I don't understand why it is ambiguous, since `pointType` can't be deduced as `std::chrono::time_point` because it doesn't have `operator[]` and `size()` member function.

P.S. I tried something else to work it out, but I only got more confused testing a program which use `std::valarray`. When I include both `<valarray>` and `"algebra.h"`, and try to make a difference between two valarrays, I expected the compiler to complain about ambiguous definition of `operator-`, since `std::valarray` already has implementation for binary operators. But this doesn't happen: it compiles using the `<valarray>` implementation. Why this doesn't throw an error?

Comment: In short, you should not add operator overloads for cases where there is not an operand of a class that you wrote.  Name lookup for the operator may not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ambiguous because the compiler only looks at the function signature to test for ambiguity, not the body of the function. In your example, this is the function signature:

```
template<typename pointType>
pointType operator-(pointType a, const pointType & b)
```

Here, the template parameter `pointType` could be deduced as `std::chrono::time_point`. However, there is already a binary minus operator declared in the `chrono` header for `std::chrono::time_point` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/operator_arith2). This is what is causing the ambiguity error.

To solve this problem, you should first consider whether you need such a generic binary minus operator. The problem you are currently experiencing will not be unique to `std::chrono::time_point`, but will also occur with any other header that contains a class with a member or non-member binary minus operator, where both arguments are of the same type (or could implicitly convert into the same type). Perhaps a simple set of function overloads for the types in question:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> operator-(const std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T>& b);

template<typename T, size_t N>
std::array<T,N> operator-(const std::array<T,N>& a, const std::array<T,N>& b);
```

This would be the safest option. You could also not use operator overloading altogether, and stick to a conventional function:

```
template<typename T>
T pointwise_subtract(const T& a, const T& b);
```

If you have a c++20 compiler, you could use concepts. If you insist on using non-member operator templates, you may have to use SFINAE-based template metaprogramming, a more advanced and less readable technique:

```
//enable this template if the type T has a member method "size" and 
//    subscript operator accepting variables of type "size_t"
template<typename T, typename=std::void_t<
                            decltype(std::declval<T>().size()),
                            decltype(std::declval<T>()[std::declval<size_t>()])
                                         >
T operator-(const T& a, const T& b);
```

This will remove your ambiguity error.

Comment: I didn't know the ambiguity test was for the function signature only! Thanks! But at this point I don't understand why the compiler doesn't complain about the ambiguity for valarray operators.

Comment: @dariobaron its because the operators already defined for valarray are more specialised than the generic operator you've defined above. They have signatures like so: template<typename T> std::valarray<T> operator-(const std::valarray<T>&, const std::valarray<T>&). Notice how they arguments are specific types of std::valarray. In this case, during overload resolution, the compiler will prefer the more specialised templates over the more generic ones.

Comment: Thank you very much!